# Kivy: bind two methods to be called one after the other

Tags: python, kivy

I have a class C with two methods, a and b, and i want one of them (b) to be always called after the other (a)

```
class C(Widget) :
 def __init__(self) :
  super(C, self).__init__() 
  self.bind(a=self.b)  # something like this 
 def a(self) : pass
 def b(self) : pass
```

How?

Answer (score 0):

How about calling b from a.

```
def a(self) :
    #some code
    self.b()
```

Comment: No. Because each instance of C will override a. That's how I'm using it. And the existence of b has to be hidden behind the curtains.

Comment: @MatiasMorant you need to be more specific in you question then.

Comment: using kivy, you can do (if self was a Button) : ```self.bind(on_release=another_function)```, which means another_function will be called after the function on_release,  which is an event. What i want is that same behavior, but instead of using a predefined method like on_release, to use my own method

Comment: yes i have read that. But if i bind my two methods just as i would bind any other two kivy events, it doesn't work. I tried registering my method a as an event with register_event_type() but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite remember why doesn't it work through binding, but I think it has something to do with using different objects e.g. binding to an old method that isn't executed or something in that sense.

This is where `super()` comes to the rescue. You see, `super()` isn't only for calling `__init__()` of the class you inherit from, it has other purposes too.

I just replaced `__init__()` with `<overridden method>()`:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyBase(Button):
    def overridden(self, *args):
        self.stable()

    def stable(self, *args):
        print('stable')

class MyButton(MyBase):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_release=self.overridden)

    def overridden(self, *args):
        # run before overriden stuff
        super(MyButton, self).overridden()

        print('new overridden')

        # run after overridden stuff
        super(MyButton, self).overridden()
runTouchApp(MyButton())
```